# Encoded polylines using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, maps

I've been given some encoded polylines to display on a google map. However I'm using JQuery for a lot of the front end functions and am now stuck trying to find the correct syntax for displaying encoded polylines using JQuery. The standard syntax for adding an encoded polyline is

```
var polyline = new GPolyline.fromEncoded({
  color: "#0000ff",
  weight: 4,
  opacity: 0.8,
  points: "_gkxEv}|vNM]kB}B}@q@YKg@IqCGa@EcA?c",
  levels: "P@B@D??@@?D?CA?B",
  zoomFactor: 2,
  numLevels: 18
});
map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

Obviously this doesn't work with JQuery. to add a normal polyline with JQuery you'd use

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: stationPathCoordinates1,
            strokeColor: "#20B5B3",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 4
```

Where StationPathCoordinates is the array of long and lats. I now have this array in an encoded polyline. I assumed it may be new google.maps.Polyline.fromEncoded but this doens't work. Anyone know the syntax for this in JQuery or if it even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Added a bounty to see if I could help you get some answers here :-)

Comment: Without building an example, I'm not sure why the original code would fail 'with jQuery'. Generally, jQuery is just a library of functions that help you to reuse code in a browser neutral way and shouldn't affect your ability to use 'ordinary' javascript code. There are, of course, issues surrounding jQuery's use of the '$' symbol, so something similar could be the case here. I apologize if I'm wrong, but I'm seeing more and more questions that refer to jQuery, when it's inclusion in the discussion is completely unwarranted.

Comment: thanks Andy! belugabob - the original javascript syntax for this causes an error which firebug describes as a 'non existent function' hence why I am assuming the syntax is different when using the JQuery framework

Comment: Don't forget to award Steffen the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @belugabob pointed out already, there shouldn't be any reason for conflicts with jQuery in general while using APIs like the Google Maps JavaScript API.

That said, and without seeing a full example, I can only deduce the following:

- The two code fragments you are presenting seem to stem from two entirely different versions of the Google Maps JavaScript API, namely [Google Maps JavaScript API V2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Encoded_Polylines) for the former and [Google Maps JavaScript API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline) for the latter (see section *PolylineOptions object specification* there).

  - The V2 API version [has been deprecated](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html) as of may 19, 2010, but will be supported for a period of 3 years as per [Googles respective deprecation policy](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_4_4).
  - The V3 API version **does not (yet) support encoded polylines**, see [Thors answer](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/msg/87ac28c52c1c1865) to point 5 in this [migration to V3](http://groups.google.vu/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/eb60abf1994047b0) thread (see [Encoded polylines vs Polyline class](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/e83925f34b2b4b76/a150242a14568049) for some background on this change, if desired).

So in case you need to maintain using encoded polylines you have two options:

1. Continue to use the V2 API, which implies making your first code fragment work as it should; you'll need to provide more details then for us to figure out what's wrong with your code (as jQuery is most likely not to blame here!), two points upfront though:

   - **Best guess**: the API version mix and your comment regarding belugabobs question is suggesting that you might simply be missing some or including the wrong dependencies!
   - Another observation: at least according to the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility.html) the encoded points and levels in your first code fragments do not match.
2. Upgrade to the V3 API, which implies decoding your encoded polylines to an `Array` or `MVCArray` of `LatLng`. I'm not aware of an official example, but for a starting point you could look into [Esas answer](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/msg/36bae1629cd8d705) within the [Encoded polylines?](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/3d4a6e674b135bd5/36bae1629cd8d705?#36bae1629cd8d705) thread, which is pointing towards the`decodeLine()` function in the Google Polyline Utility source code as well as a sample decoder.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks Steffen, looking at the code I inherited more thoroughly there was a mixture of v2 and v3 api. I have removed all v2 code and migrated to v3 and used standard polylines until they are supported in v3 of the api.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question for @RichW.  Bounty awarded :-)

Comment: @Andy - thanks for making this investigation a more worthwhile effort even and helping out RichW like so :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to now be some kind of support for encoded polylines.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#encoding

The documentation is not great but I also found an example here :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-encodings.html

so that should give you an idea about how to do it.